# PowerShell doesn't recognize basic cmdlets

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

When calling basic cmdlets in PowerShell 3.0, PowerShell does not recognize them:

```
Write-Host "Test"
# returns error "The term 'Write-Host' is not recognized as the name of a 
# cmdlet, function, (etc.)
```

The same holds true for many other basic PowerShell scripts.

$Env.Path is set to:

> C:\Windows\system32; C:\Windows; C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Bin\; c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;
>   c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
>   c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\; c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\; C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\; C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\; C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\; C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\; C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\

$Env.PSModulePath displays:

> C:\Users\{username}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;;C:\Program
>   Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules;C:\Program
>   Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\

Comment: `/sfc scannow`?

Comment: Gosh.. This seems that your system is seriously having issue. Its not about  Powershell. I second with *sfc* . Secondly I would like you to restore to the last known good configuration if possible.

Comment: Agreed with the `SFC /SCANNOW` recommendation; another useful piece of information that you should provide if possible is the value of `$PSModulePath`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Updated. (As an aside, it's not my server, so I'm avoiding any administrative type actions like sfc/last known good)

Comment: You've definitely gotten something corrupted; `$env:PSModulePath` should contain (among others) `C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` and `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`. As it's not your server, you should probably report this to your administrator so that s/he can fix it.

Comment: oh my, looks like someone has been playing with SQL :P
Agree with the others something is wrong with the server not PowerShell here